# Are multiple conditions in statement computed sequentially?

Tags: python

if the first condition is false, which means no matter what the second condition is output will be false. So will the second condition get computed ?

```
if a > b and b > c:
   do something ...
```

Comment: No, it won't. This is called short-circuit evaluation, and every language I can think of implements it.

Comment: No, it will not, if the first clause of an `and` expression is `False`, the second will not get computed; similarly, if the first clause of an `or` expression is `True`, the second will not get computed.

Answer (score 0):

Python short-circuits boolean expressions. As soon as the result of the entire expression is known, evaluation stops.

If you're using `and` and the left-hand expression is `False`, the entire expression must be `False`, so the right-hand expression wil not be evaluated.

Similarly for `or` if the left-hand expression is `True`, the right-hand expression will not be evaluated.

Consequently, you should be careful about including function calls with side-effects in boolean expressions. They can lead to program behavior that is difficult to predict.